# Thread was being aborted. - Garbage Collection Handling

Tags: vb.net

I am facing this error when trying to run my VB.NET application in Framework V4.0. The program starts off with a complex SQL select which uses a connection from a connection pool to execute. It takes around 20 minutes to execute.

After the records are loaded into the program and some logical processing takes place, the program attempts to retrieve further data, as can be seen in 'GetContPensionLinked'. This leads to the use of the OpenConnection() method, which uses an ODBC driver to connect to an Informix server.

The error is thrown sporadically. Any ideas what might be causing it? I am willing to provide further details if necessary.

```
Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalCompareExchange(IntPtr handle, Object value, Object oldValue, Boolean isPinned)
   at System.WeakReference.set_Target(Object value)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.MakeNonPooledObject(Object owningObject, DbConnectionPoolCounters performanceCounters)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at MITA.SABS.DataBaseAccess.DataBaseCommon.OpenConnection()
   at MITA.SABS.DataBaseAccess.DataBaseCommon.PrepareCommand(String SQL, List`1 ParamList)
   at MITA.SABS.DataBaseAccess.DataBaseAccess.GetReader(String sql, Object[] paramList)
   at KoDI.Query.Execute()
   at MITA.SABS.DataAccess.SABS.DeficiencyContributionBonusPaymentRepository.GetContPensionLinked(DCBClaimant input)
   at MITA.SABS.Domain.SABS.DeficiencyContributionBonusPayment.checkContPension(List`1 input, Boolean check)
   at MITA.SABS.Domain.SABS.DeficiencyContributionBonusPayment.ExecuteReport(ThreadFunctionParamWithReturnAndTrans`2 param)Source: mscorlib Message: Thread was being aborted.
```

Comment: ThreadAbortExceptions are squirrely little beasts, and are often times more informative than indicative of any specific action that needs to be taken. Seeing that there is a call in the trace to what appears to be some unmanaged code, you might be looking at a thread termination there that isn't getting handled until the return to managed code takes place. A strategic "try/finally" block at a conspicuous location might be enough to consume it harmlessly unless you're doing some odd thread aborts yourself.

Comment: @DavidW I am wrapping the 'Execute Report' functionality in a Try Catch statement. Is this sufficient to consume the thread was being aborted error?

Comment: *Maybe*. Catch that exception specifically and see what happens. When caught, it is subject to being rethrown at the end of the corresponding catch(). Are you doing any explicit thread.abort calls? Keep in mind this exception is fired any time Thread.Abort() occurs, so it technically isn't an error - it's just letting the runtime know a thread has been unceremoniously killed.

Comment: @DavidW No, I'm not calling thread.abort anywhere. I've just created a new threadabortexception handler which attempts to resetabort() the thread. I shall keep you posted on the (if any) progress made. Thanks for your help thus far!